# Could not deduce [..] from the context - Is it possible to avoid explicit constraints?

Tags: haskell

Given the code below (that can be modified and compiled online [here](http://rextester.com/BDCXL11499)), the compilation gives this error:

> Could not deduce (Num a1) arising from a use of ‘solveFormulaPart’ from the context:
>
> StateGettable IdState a
>
> bound by the type signature for:
>
> solveFormula :: StateGettable IdState a => IdState -> StateFormula1 a  StateMonad IdState a
>
> Possible fix: add (Num a1) to the context of the data constructor ‘StateFormula1’

Is there any solution that could remove the need for having to explicitly give all the constraints on the `StateFormula1` and `StateFormulaPart` data constructors? (ideally, the same `StateFormula` instance should be reusable as-is with any `State` instance, as long as the underlying type seemingly matches the required constraints at use site)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies           #-}


import           Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import           GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data StateFormulaPart a where
    Constant :: a -> StateFormulaPart a
    Property :: (StateProperty a) -> StateFormulaPart a


type SFP a = StateFormulaPart a


data StateFormula1 b where
    StateFormula1 :: SFP a
                  -> (a -> b)
                  -> StateFormula1 b


class StateFormula formula where
    -- todo remove this if the kind can be inferred using another method
    explicitKind :: formula a -> formula a


instance StateFormula StateFormula1


data StateProperty a =
    StateProperty { propertyKey     :: String
                  , propertyDefault ::  a
                  }


class Monad (StateMonad state) => State state where
    type StateMonad state :: * -> *
    type StateGettable state :: * -> Constraint
    getPropertyValue :: StateGettable state a => state -> StateProperty a -> StateMonad state a


class (StateFormula formula, State state) => StateSolver state formula where
    solveFormula :: StateGettable state a => state -> (formula a) -> StateMonad state a
    solveFormulaPart :: StateGettable state a => state -> (SFP a) -> StateMonad state a
    

data IdState = IdState


instance State IdState where
    type StateMonad IdState = MaybeT IO
    type StateGettable IdState = Num


instance StateSolver IdState StateFormula1 where
    -- solveFormulaPart :: Num a => IdState -> SFP a -> MaybeT IO a
    solveFormulaPart s (Constant x) = return x
    solveFormulaPart s (Property p) = do
        liftIO $ print (propertyKey p)
        return (propertyDefault p)

    -- solveFormula :: Num a => IdState -> StateFormula1 a -> MaybeT IO a
    solveFormula s (StateFormula1 p1 f) = do
        x1 <- solveFormulaPart s p1
        return $ f x1
    

workingFormula :: StateFormula1 Int
workingFormula = StateFormula1 (Property $ StateProperty "test" 5 :: StateFormulaPart Int) id


main = runMaybeT $ solveFormula IdState workingFormula
```

Comment: Where is `StateFormulaN`? What are you *hoping* to write?

Comment: `StateFormulaN` was a shortcut for `StateFormula1` to eg `StateFormula6` (I have edited my question as this was unclear).
I'm hoping to write a system for generating forms with interdependent fields, that should be compilable to JS (with Haste) or to another kind of applications (thus requiring different `State` instances).
If it was possible for the base form code to be ignorant of the specific constraints (while keeping the compilation errors when the constraints actually do not match), the code of each application could directly reuse it, limiting the amount of code generation involved.

Comment: Also, this is for a Haskell learning project, which should actually end up in a real-world application (the reason why I chose Haskell for this, besides the language in itself, is the type system, allowing to ensure at compile time that everything is seemingly right, starting from a form configuration written in YAML, and QuickCheck, which should really come in handy for various testing purposes)

Comment: Please don't turn on GHC extensions that you don't even use, in particular not so adventurous ones as `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `DeriveAnyClass`. Generally, and for StackOverflow questions in particular.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry, I'll keep that in mind (those were residuals of my previous tests)

Comment: You don't need any constraint on `StateFormulaPart`, you just need a `StateGettable state a` constraint in `StateFormula1` (which also means it must have another paramater - `state`). In any case, `StateFormula1` doesn't seem like a very interesting type, so it isn't really clear what the actual use case is (you've stated what you hope to accomplish, not what you have tried to do).

Comment: @user2407038 What I have tried to do is to have generic `StateFormula[N]` definitions, which could be applied to different `State` values, while only getting compilation errors when trying to use a `StateFormula[N]` on a `State` with non-matching constraints. Anyway, I think that I'm starting to grasp why this isn't possible - thanks for putting me back on the right track! (if you can post an answer, I will gladly accept it)